# Displaying the backend data in dropdown list using JavaScript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have created the front-end with materializecss and am getting the back-end data from aws. Here, I wanna display the list of items from aws to my front-end dropdown list.But, it is fully blank and couldn't see any of the data in dropdown list.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
      <select id="entries">
         <option value="0">- Select -</option>
      </select>
      <label>Course</label>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('select').material_select();
       $('.datepicker').pickadate({
           selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
           selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
           today: 'Today',
           clear: 'Clear',
           close: 'Ok',
           closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
       });
   });

   $('#textarea1').val('New Text');
   $('#textarea1').trigger('autoresize');    

   courseList();

   function courseList() {

       AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
       AWS.config.update({
           accessKeyId: 'aaaaaaaaaaa',
           secretAccessKey: 'aaaaaaaaaaa'
       });
       var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
       let scanPar = {
           TableName: 'course',
           Limit: 100
       };

       docClient.scan(scanPar, function(err, data) {
           if (err) {
               console.log(err, null);
           } else {
               console.log(null, data);
               data.Items.forEach(function(courseEntry) {
                   $('#entries').append('<option>' + courseEntry.title + '</option>');                           
               });
           }
       });
   }
</script>
```

When I tried to display it without drop down list(i.e) within para `<p>` tag, it works. And also in console.log, it displays right.

Comment: move `$('select').material_select();` to below `data.Items.forEach(() {});` block

Comment: Cool. It worked. Can you explain it?

Comment: Updated the answer with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$('select').material_select();` is inside  [`$(document).ready(function() {`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/),. This means it will run immediately after the `DOM` is loaded.

But `docClient.scan` is an asynchronous call. Depending on the server, it will take some time to fetch the data and bind to the `select`.

So, you should run the `.material_select()` on your element **after** your `select` is populated.

```
docClient.scan(scanPar, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, null);
    } else {
        console.log(null, data);
        data.Items.forEach(function(courseEntry) {
            $('#entries').append('<option>' + courseEntry.title + '</option>');                           
        });
        $('select').material_select();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running `courseList()` outside of your `$(document).ready()` function.

Could it be running before the select box is initialised?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).